# How can I adjust the brightness of two LCD backlights?

Tags: led, backlight

I've just received a PCB I designed with two LCD screens. Unfortunately, the LCDs were black. I think it's due to a wrong schematic for converting BL to LEDK. In the current application code bl is driven by GPIO 26 of a rp2040 minimum brightness is 0% PWM and maximum brightness 100% PWM. The LCDs require 2.8V for minimum brightness and 3.3V for maximum brightness. Each screen uses three white LEDS in parallel with a total consumption of 60 mA per screen.

[image]

If I bridge LEDK and GND the screens work fine at what I guess is full brightness.
The same code works with two LCDs on a breadboard (each takes BL and converts it to LEDK.)

My schematic is attached.

[Here is the inspiration schematic.](https://www.waveshare.net/w/upload/f/f5/1.47inch_LCD_Module_SchDoc.pdf)

[These are the LCDs I'm using.](https://vi.aliexpress.com/i/1005003771379232.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2vnm)

How can I change the circuit to make it work?

Comment: How do you drive the BL wire to transistors? Is the transistor wired with correct pinout? Are the resistors of correct value?

Comment: What happens if you bridge BL to 3.3V?

Comment: Are you actually driving the BL line with a PWM signal? (Pulses?).  You list 0V, 3.3V and 2.8V, those are voltage levels not PWM values.  An example of PWM values would be 0%, 100%, and 80%. The more % time the BL signal pulse is high the brighter the LED backlight.  (Show your driver circuit for the BL input.)

Comment: Are you trying to use the so called "Analog Output" of a standard Arduino I/O to drive the BL line?

Comment: @Justme the connections are right as BL goes straight to GPIO 26 of the rp2040 chip. The resistors are the same as in the schematics of another device that uses the same LCD

Comment: @brhans I have no clean access to BL as it's a wire in the PCB.

Comment: @Nedd correct, updated the post specifying that is PWM from a rp2040

Comment: @nicco82 you can surely access BL where it's connected to R8 & R14 ...